# Flipping an upside-down 3d figure in opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es

i am new to android opengl. I rendered an 3d figure, but the issue is it is upside down, i tried to use glRotatef(), but couldn't get the correct figure,could someone help me?
my code for ondraw()

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 5.0f, 30.0f, -15.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
    gl.glScalef(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);     
    p.draw_tablelamp1(gl);
    p.draw_tablelamp2(gl);
}
```

Comment: *i tried to use glRotatef()* well how did you try to use it  ? (or more clearly WHERE) btw AFAIC, using gluLookAt and glTranslatef/glRotatef/glScalef in the same code is never really clear

Comment: i used glrotatef(180,0,1,0) in between glscalef and draw_tablelamp1, the problem is that it is not rotating on its own axis,

Answer (score 0):

*Put your device upside down*

Try to set camera up vector the other way around:

```
GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 5.0f, 30.0f, -15.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
```

You can also try to change the Viewport by switching Y axis Top with Bottom.

Finally you can try rotate the thing:

```
gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
gl.glScalef(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);     
gl.glRotatef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 3.1415f);     
gl.glRotatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 3.1415f);     
p.draw_tablelamp1(gl);
p.draw_tablelamp2(gl);
```

Comment: why do you need 2 rotations ? and putting the device upside down only works if every single item you are drawing is upside down

Comment: Just for readability, you could do this in one rotation but then the rotation vector would not be so simple to understand. See also [rotations](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/)

Comment: I'm not following you, to flipp an object you only need to rotate it around the  viewing axis by Pi, no ?

Comment: Lets say you have an object like a Paining. Its upside down. Then in order to have it rotate in such a way to have it the right way up you have to rotate it along the viewing axis. There is also the element of what that axis should be. Ill make some corrections in the answer to compensate for you having +Y as the top. You might also want to have it upside down in reference to the +Y axis, then its easyest by doing 2 rotations as I see it.